# Laravel project not working in cpanel faced error Target class [App\Http\Controllers\fileController] does not exist

Tags: laravel, cpanel

Laravel project not working in cpanel faced error Target class [App\Http\Controllers\fileController] does not exist. But project completely running locally without no error. 
**Error image**
[image: Error image]

**route.php**

[image: route.php]

**AuthorController.php**

[image: AuthorController.php]

Please help me out. Advanced thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you provide this `fileController` which should be `FileController`? since the `AuthorController` isn't relevant ... and please refrain from putting up images of code, code is text, it can be added to your question directly

Answer (score 0):

The error appears to be straight foward --You are appear to be missing the definition of the FileController and somewhere within your routes files you are calling the controller.

```
Route::resource('files', 'FilesController');
```

To fix an issue like this, make sure you had not renamed any of your controllers to a different name or you could simply run artisan

```
php artisan make:controller FilesController -r
```

to get past this issue. Also, try and stick to resourceful controllers as the verbs such as "PUT", "PATCH", "GET" etc. make decrease the readability of your code. If you don't with to expose all the method in a resourceful controller within your route you could have something like

```
Route::resource('files', 'FilesController')->except('index','show');
```

and so forth.